# Is there any way to run a search against all columns and rows in the grid in ag-grid?

Tags: ag-grid

My title pretty much says it all. I want to run a full text search (simply contains or like search) against every column and row in an ag-grid.  Is this possible?  This is built into datatables.

Answer (score 5):

Ag-grid Doc - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-quick/#quick-filter-example

Plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/NaDAQYvXoo2P6vxdvPVB?p=preview

Add a text box with function onFilterTextBoxChanged()

```
<input type="text" id="filter-text-box" placeholder="Filter..." oninput="onFilterTextBoxChanged()"/>
```

setQuickFilter for Ag-grid with the value entered by the user in this text box

```
function onFilterTextBoxChanged() {
    gridOptions.api.setQuickFilter(document.getElementById('filter-text-box').value);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, It is possible. Please refer to https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-quick/

```html
<input type="text" id="filter-text-box" placeholder="Filter..." oninput="onFilterTextBoxChanged()"/>
```

```
function onFilterTextBoxChanged() {
    gridOptions.api.setQuickFilter(document.getElementById('filter-text-box').value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not natively, but you can implement you own external Filter

Check section External Filtering here https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid-filtering/index.php.